# How to save and display image into database without using move uploaded or copy functions in php

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

How to save and display image into database without using move uploaded or copy functions in php ? 
Is it possible to do that without saving the images into directories and saving them to database with some datatype for that particular field ?

Comment: You're trying to save the actual file in a database field as a `blob`? Just use, for example, `file_get_contents`

Comment: Of course it's possible.  A quick Google search for something like "PHP save uploaded file to database" also reveals that it's quite common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) datatype it is direct save image in the database.

here one example of [PHP MySQL BLOB](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/).hope it is help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to get the base64 encoded image and save it to your DB.

```
$image_as_string = base64_encode( file_get_contents( 'image.jpg' ) ) 
// now save dat string to your database.
```

Hope it helps.